# LongListSelector ItemTemplate not growing

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have an itemtemplate with just two texts blocks in it but when a text block is growing because of a word wrap, the itemtemplate grid is not growing.
How can I do that ? Thanks for your help !

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ArtistTemplate">
        <Grid Height="60" Width="436">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" MinHeight="34" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="10,0" Foreground="White" FontSize="26" FontWeight="Bold" Height="34" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding NbAlbum, Converter={StaticResource Converters_IntToStringWithNbAlbum}}" Margin="10,0,10,-21" Foreground="White" FontSize="12" Height="16" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the height of grid to "Auto".

```
 <Grid Height="Auto" Width="436">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" MinHeight="34" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="10,0" Foreground="White" FontSize="26" FontWeight="Bold" Height="34" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding NbAlbum, Converter={StaticResource Converters_IntToStringWithNbAlbum}}" Margin="10,0,10,-21" Foreground="White" FontSize="12" Height="16" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you ! Sigh ... Just feel like a noob ;)